# CaptureDumpFileOnDevice return 0 and GetLastError = ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER (87)

Tags: c#, windows, dump

My .Net application runs on windows ce 6 (on Toradex).
Sometimes it get stuck and I want to create a dump file.
I've created an application that call

```
CaptureDumpFileOnDevice(DWORD dwProcessId, DWORD dwThreadId, LPCWSTR pwzExtraFilesPath)
```

but it always return `0` and  `GetLastError` = `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`. Even when I pass values `0` for the `Ids` (means current process and current thread) and null for the path.

I didn't find the related keys in the registry (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa526063.aspx) so I added the 'DumpDirectory' and 'DontUpload' keys.

1. Do you have a suggestion why I get `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`?
2. Do I need to set all the Error Reporting keys in the registry?
3. Do you know an existing application that takes dump on windows ce?
4. Do you have another idea how to deal a stuck application while not in debug mode?

Edit:
Usage in code:

```
[DllImport("Coredll.dll")]
private static extern int CaptureDumpFileOnDevice
( uint dwProcessId,
  uint dwThreadId,
  string pwzExtraFilesPath);

[DllImport("coredll.dll")]
private static extern uint GetLastError();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var result = CaptureDumpFileOnDevice(0, 0, null);
    if (result == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error! failed to capture dump file for thread id {0} got {1}, {2}",
        threadId, Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(), GetLastError());
    } 
}
```

Comment: show as **How** you call this function.

Comment: var result = CaptureDumpFileOnDevice(0, 0, null);
                if (result == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error! failed to capture dump file for thread id {0} got {1}, {2}",
                        threadId, Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(),
                        GetLastError());
                }

Comment: how does `CaptureDumpFileOnDevice` is defined in your app, after all , its a C++ function, do you have any p/invoke  signature?

Comment: I also tried using a specific process id and one of its thread id but I got the same results

Comment: [DllImport("Coredll.dll")]
        private static extern int CaptureDumpFileOnDevice(
            uint dwProcessId,
            uint dwThreadId,
            string pwzExtraFilesPath);

        [DllImport("coredll.dll")]
        private static extern uint GetLastError();

Answer (score 0):

```
[DllImport("Coredll.dll")] 
private static extern int CaptureDumpFileOnDevice( uint dwProcessId, uint dwThreadId, string pwzExtraFilesPath);
```

this looks completley wrong. 
try:

```
[DllImport("Coredll.dll")] 
private static extern int CaptureDumpFileOnDevice( unsigned long dwProcessId, unsigned long dwThreadId, InptPtr pwzExtraFilesPath);
```

when you want to pass the string , convert it to C-style unicode string with

```
Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemUni(YourStringHere)
```

in order to pass `null` - pass `IntPtr.Zero` instead.

Comment: Tried it. Still the same outcome :(